# How to not show text before hover

Tags: html, css

I've got an image in the background and I've divided the space into four colored sections.  How can I get a section to reduce opacity (which would allow for image in background to show), but also show a colored box with text, WITHOUT the `<h2>` showing before it is hovered?

This is how I'd like it to look like before hover:

[image: this is how I'd like it to look like before hover]

This is how it currently looks like when hovered:

[image: this is how it currently looks like when hovered]

What it currently looks like before hover:

[image: what it currently looks like before hover]

This is my current code:

```
<style>
        html, body {
            height: 100%;
            padding: 0; 
            margin: 0; 
            display: block;
            height: 100%;
            margin: 0 auto;
        max-width: 100%;
        background-image: url('../images/4.jpg');
        background-repeat: no-repeat;
        background-position: center center;
        background-size: 100% 100%;
        }
        .container {
            max-width: 100%;
            max-height: 100%;
        }
        .homePage div { 
            width: 50%; 
            height: 50%;
            float: left; 
        }
        #tRight { 
            top: 0;
            left: 50%;
            right: 0;
            bottom: 50%;
            background: rgba(67, 70, 75, 1); 
        }
            #tRight:hover {
            background: rgba(67, 70, 75, .3);
        }

        #bLeft { 
            top: 50%;
            left: 0;
            right: 50%;
            bottom: 0;
            background: rgba(251, 201, 80, 1); 
        }
            #bLeft:hover {
            background: rgba(251, 201, 80, .3); 
        }

        #bRight { 
            top: 50%;
            left: 50%;
            right: 0;
            bottom : 0;
            background: rgba(186, 77, 25, 1);  
        }
            #bRight:hover {
            background: rgba(186, 77, 25, .3);
        }

        .logo {
            position: absolute;
            top: 30%;
            left: 44%;
            z-index: 10;
            display: block;
        }
            .logo:hover {

        }
        #tLeft { 
        top: 0;
        left: 0;
        right: 50%;
        bottom 50%;
        background: rgba(10, 95, 107, 1); 
        display: inline-block;
        position: relative;
    }
        #tLeft:hover .hover h2{
            transition: opacity .75s ease-out; 
            position: absolute;
            top: 15%;
            bottom: 15%;
            left: 0;
            right: 0;
            background-color: rgba(153,153,153,.9);
            padding: 20px;
            font-family: 'Roboto Condensed', sans-serif;
            font-weight: 800;
            font-size: 2em;
            color: white;
            opacity: 1;
        }
    </style>
</head>

<body class="homePage">

    <header>
        <a href="#"><img src="asset/images/LOGO.png" class="logo"></a>
    </header>

    <div id="tLeft" alt="1">
        <div class="hover">
            <h2><strong>Graphic Design</strong> Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. </h2>
        </div>
    </div>

    <div id="tRight" alt="1">
    </div>

    <div id="bLeft" alt="1">
    </div>

    <div id="bRight" alt="1">
    </div>

</body>
```

Answer (score 0):

#### Hi ritchieRitchie,

I'm not sure if I correctly understand Your question but here comes a litle bit modified your code in snipped with solution.

Generally I hid text before container div is hovered and when container is hovered change background opacity like in other three. And also added same sample texts to all 4 sections.

```css
html,
body {
  height: 100%;
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
  display: block;
  height: 100%;
  margin: 0 auto;
  max-width: 100%;
  background-image: url('https://s10.postimg.org/dibczxad5/mallard0.png');
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-position: center center;
  background-size: 100% 100%;
}
        
.homePage div {
  width: 50%;
  height: 50%;
  float: left;
}

.logo {
  position: absolute;
  top: 30%;
  left: 44%;
  z-index: 10;
  display: block;
}

.container {
  max-width: 100%;
  max-height: 100%;
}

#tLeft {
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  right: 50%;
  bottom 50%;
  background: rgba(10, 95, 107, 1);
}

#tLeft:hover {
  background-color: rgba(10, 95, 107, .3);
}

#tRight {
  top: 0;
  left: 50%;
  right: 0;
  bottom: 50%;
  background: rgba(67, 70, 75, 1);
}

#tRight:hover {
  background: rgba(67, 70, 75, .3);
}

#bLeft {
  top: 50%;
  left: 0;
  right: 50%;
  bottom: 0;
  background: rgba(251, 201, 80, 1);
}

#bLeft:hover {
  background: rgba(251, 201, 80, .3);
}

#bRight {
  top: 50%;
  left: 50%;
  right: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  background: rgba(186, 77, 25, 1);
}

#bRight:hover {
  background: rgba(186, 77, 25, .3);
}

.hover-container {
  position: absolute;
}

.hover-container .hover h2 {
  visibility: hidden;
}

.hover-container:hover .hover h2 {
  visibility: visible;
  transition: opacity .75s ease-out;
  position: absolute;
  top: 15%;
  bottom: 15%;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
  padding: 20px;
  font-family: 'Roboto Condensed', sans-serif;
  font-weight: 800;
  font-size: 1em;
  color: white;
  background-color: rgba(153, 153, 153, .9);
  opacity: 1;
}
```

```html
<body class="homePage">

  <header>
    <a href="#"><img src="asset/images/LOGO.png" class="logo"></a>
  </header>

  <div id="tLeft" class="hover-container" alt="1">
    <div class="hover">
      <h2><strong>Graphic Design1</strong> Lorem ipsum</h2>
    </div>
  </div>

  <div id="tRight" class="hover-container" alt="1">
    <div class="hover">
      <h2><strong>Graphic Design2</strong> Lorem ipsum </h2>
    </div>
  </div>

  <div id="bLeft" class="hover-container" alt="1">
    <div class="hover">
      <h2><strong>Graphic Design3</strong> Lorem ipsum</h2>
    </div>
  </div>

  <div id="bRight" class="hover-container" alt="1">
    <div class="hover">
      <h2><strong>Graphic Design4</strong> Lorem ipsum</h2>
    </div>
  </div>

</body>
```

If You want to hide element and act like it isn't there use `display` instead of `visibility` rule:

```
.hover-container .hover h2 {
  display: none;
}

.hover-container:hover .hover h2 {
  display: initial;
}
```

More informations about difference between `display` and `visibility` e.g. on [W3Schools page](https://www.w3schools.com/css/css_display_visibility.asp).

#### Cheers

Comment: Thank you so much.  This is exactly what I was looking for.  I'm new to html5 and css3, and wasn't aware of the visibility property.